# How to extract a value from Option[Double] in JNI?

Tags: scala, java-native-interface

I'm able to extract `jobject` from `Option[Double]` using `get()` method:

```
jmethodID getMethodID = env->GetMethodID(optionClass, "get", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
jobject volObj = env->CallObjectMethod(pointObj, getMethodID);
```

However, I don't see a way to extract the actual Double value from Option. How to do that?

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to be scala? Looks like some .NET thing.

Comment: This is JNI (Java Native Interface) for Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can call [Double.doubleValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleValue--) to unbox the object to double.

```
jclass doubleClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Double");
jmethodID doubleMethod =
    (*env)->GetMethodID(env, doubleClass, "doubleValue", "()D");
jdouble d = (*env)->CallDoubleMethod(env, valObj, doubleMethod);
```